# Grammarly says it's incorrect for passive voice- My tenet of life is that there is nothing that cannot be accomplished with effort

Tags: grammar

> My tenet of life is that there is nothing that cannot be accomplished with effort.

Grammarly says it's incorrect, so what is wrong here? And is there a better phrasing than this?

Comment: Double negatives can sometimes confuse so *"My tenet of life is that with effort anything can be accomplished"* might be clearer

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the passive voice. It's a rule promulgated by those reprobates Strunk & White (and others). The reason your sentence is great is  uses the passive voice in exactly the way that it's meant to be used: as an information packaging construction. It shunts to the end of the sentence the most salient and important word here, the word *effort*. It is a double effective sentence, because it uses two information packaging constructions in conjunction to great effect.

Comment: Grammarly should only be used to *suggest* that something is wrong.

Comment: The sentence is correct, but those who advocate the use of 'positive....' may argue against it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., your disdain for Strunk & White puzzles me. The problem with the passive voice is that many writers (especially inexperienced ones) tend to use it as a crutch--so much so that their prose becomes turgid and unreadable. Of course it is no sin to use the passive voice if you know what you are doing, but to use it repeatedly in an effort to sound smarter than you are is wrong.

Comment: @RobJarvis Nobody has ever managed to produce any evidence that bad writers overuse the passive. On why every linguist hates Strunk & White see here: [**50 years of Stupid Grammar Advice**](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/50years.pdf). Geoff Pullum lets them off lightly. Regarding the passive, a basic point might be that if someone wants to pontificate against the passive, they should a) know what a passive is and b) be able to take their own advice. at least within their very own chapter on it. S&W fail on both counts. Disdain is the correct word.

Comment: @RobJarvis One day you will learn to love to hate them too ... ;-)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., I can see your point from a strictly grammatical standpoint. My perspective, however, is geared more toward effective and vibrant fiction and non-fiction writing. Viewed through that lens, I still say that the passive voice should be used judiciously by those who know what they're doing. My experience teaching Freshman Composition classes gave me plenty of evidence of poor grammar practices used by novice writers, including overuse of the passive.

Comment: @Esther, here is a bit of irony: the [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/passive-voice/) website explicitly states that the passive voice is not wrong to use.

Comment: I rephrased it as - My tenet of life is that everything is possible with effort.
It follows with this- Even if it seems impossible if it's something that people do, I bravely challenge to make it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"can be accomplished" is passive voice, which Grammarly flags as a problem. As a general rule, active voice is clearer and more assertive than passive voice, which is why most grammarians shun it. In some limited styles of writing or in rare instances, the passive voice may be appropriate. As a writer, not a grammarian, my advice is to work diligently to remove the passive voice from your everyday writing. Having done that, if you find no better way to express the thought, then use it and stick your tongue out at Grammarly.

Comment: How would you suggest for this sentence then?

Comment: @Esther, I would revise the sentence to read, "My tenet of life is this: There is nothing you cannot accomplish with effort."

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any use of the passive voice here. As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong with this sentence.

As to whether there's a better phrase, that's hard to answer; there'll always be better/different ways of saying something.

Comment: "be accomplished" looks passive to me